# material-ui, useState give error of types in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

I try to use drawer from material-ui typescript. Unfortunately they have some problem with types, I think so.

So according to material-ui dock I should to add:

```
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

But it give error of syntax in consola, and VSC shows few errors about types:

> Parameter 'open' implicitly has an 'any' type
>
> Parameter 'setOpen' implicitly has an 'any' type
>
> 'useState', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type

So I found that I can use it that:

```
...
export interface iOpen {
    open: any;
}

class Topbar extends Component<{}, iOpen>{

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<iOpen>(false);
...
```

I thing there is problem, or with "open" variable that should have types, or useState, but I really don't know how it should to looks like. I'm new in types.

Comment: `But it give error of syntax in consola, and VSC shows few errors about types.` Please show us those errors.

Comment: @Nicholas Tower, I edited my post, added it